# To apply type_id operator during the construction

Tags: c++, typeid

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <cassert>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

long unsigned int hash_in_constructor;

struct A
{
    virtual void foo()
    {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }

    A()
    { 
        hash_in_constructor = typeid(this).hash_code();
    }
};


int main()
{
    cout << hash_in_constructor << endl;
    cout << typeid(A).hash_code();
}
```

[DEMO](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4227d032d331b9b3)

I expected that `hash_in_constructor` equals to `typeid(A).hash_code()` because 12.7/5:

> When typeid is used in a constructor (including the mem-initializer or
>   brace-or-equal-initializer for a non-static data member) or in a
>   destructor, or used in a function called (directly or indirectly) from
>   a constructor or destructor, if the operand of typeid refers to the
>   object under construction or destruction, typeid **yields the**
>   **std::type_info object representing the constructor or destructor’s**
>   class.

but it is not true. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two obvious problems:

1. `hash_in_constructor` is only set when `A::A` is executed, when an instance of A is constructed.

   You read it before constructing an instance of A, so it hasn't been set (just been statically initialized to zero).
2. you're comparing `typeid(A)` with `typeid(A*)`, and they're different. The `this` pointer is a pointer, remember.

Examine the output of [this version of your code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a563ce7a8540590):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <typeinfo>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

long unsigned int hash_in_constructor;

struct A {
    virtual void foo() {
        cout << "A" << endl;
    }

    A() { 
        hash_in_constructor = typeid(this).hash_code();
    }
};


int main() {
    cout << "static init = " << hash_in_constructor << endl;
    A a;
    a.foo();
    cout << "after ctor = " << hash_in_constructor << endl;
    cout << "typeid(&a) = " << typeid(&a).name() << " : " << typeid(&a).hash_code() << endl;
    cout << "typeid(a) = " << typeid(a).name() << " : " << typeid(a).hash_code() << endl;
    cout << "typeid(A) = " << typeid(A).name() << " : " << typeid(A).hash_code() << endl;
}
```

which outputs:

```
g++ -std=c++1y -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -pthread main.cpp -lcxxrt -ldl && ./a.out
static init = 0
A
after ctor = 15127845526165118748
typeid(&a) = P1A : 15127845526165118748
typeid(a) = 1A : 1295143305205299629
typeid(A) = 1A : 1295143305205299629
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `typeid(*this)` instead of `typeid(this)`, otherwise you will get the type information for `A*`, which is of course different from `A`.

Comment: You never call the constructor in your example, see here: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/732339b5ffb4dee1